# Как ограничить длину строки в RichEdit?

Tags: delphi

Как ограничить длину строки в RichEdit?

Answer (score 2):

Это делается установкой значения свойства [`TRichEdit.MaxLength`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TRichEdit.MaxLength).

Comment: @Asen, вы ссылку забыли стырить :-)

Comment: @Asen, если я отвечу на новый вопрос от ОПа, обещаете, что вам не придет удачно в голову такое же решение?

Comment: Действительно, вам показалось, что я "стыбзил" у вас идею? Нет. Честно, просто, когда я внимательно пробежался по свойствам  RichEdit`а, то обнаружил TRichEdit.MaxLength.

Comment: таки не длинна всего набранного текста (TRichEdit.MaxLength), а длинна любой строки не более, к примеру, 100 символов

Comment: @Иван Федорович Крузенштерн, у вас в вопросе полно места осталось, отредактируйте его.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в обработчике события RichBox "OnKeyPress" обрабатывать вот такой код:

```
...
if length(richedit1.lines.text)>255 then   // 255 - максимальная длина текста
richedit1.lines.text:=copy(richedit1.lines.text,0,255);
...
```

**Если каждую строку, то так:**

```
...
var leng:integer;
begin
leng:=10;   // по 10 символов
for i:=0 to richedit1.Lines.Count-1 do
if length(richedit1.Lines.Strings[i])>leng then
richedit1.Lines.Strings[i]:=copy(richedit1.Lines.Strings[i],0,leng-1)+#13;
...
```

Comment: наверное я неправильно объяснил что мне нужно... мне нужно, что б длинна строки была не больше, к примеру, 100 символов, а не длинна всего текста. Строк сколько угодно, а длинна строки не более 100 символов...вот такой вопрос...

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Изменил код.

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло... при наборе текста в Richedit этот код не ограничивает количество символов в строке...